# Sitecore 9.2 Forms - How to get Submit button field details in the submit action

Tags: sitecore-forms

We have a custom submit button which has additional properties(ex:PdfTemplate).

[image]

While trying to fetch the field values on the submit action(using formsubmitcontext.fields) I am able to get the field values of all the other fields in the form , except the submit button field.
Hence I am not able to fetch the value selected on the "Pdf Template" property in my submit context.

Can someone throw some light on this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the `custom submit button` you will get value of `forms fields` and you will not get information of `pdf template` field as this is property of form.

If you want to get `pdf template` value then create this as a `hidden field` and then you will get value of `pdf template`.

Comment: Hi.. Many thanks for the response.  Do you mean the properties of the "Submit Button field" be considered as the properties of the form? In other words, won't the submit button be treated as a form field?

Comment: "pdf template" is a property of the "custom submit button", so you will not get as a form field

Comment: Thanks again for the response. Please ignore the PDFTemplate(that I just brought to get it as an example) and I am sorry If I was not clear on my query. 

 My query was, while the formsubmitcontext.fields bringing the details/ values of all the other fields of the form(ex: single line text, checkbox etc.) it is not bringing the submit button to this collection. I am just curious on how to get the details (be it a css class / Label / or any OOTB properties) of submit button in the code while extending the submit action.

Comment: Thanks, @iMathi for explaining, I am more curious to know that why you want to get "css class / Label" on submit button?

Comment: Its again an example, I quoted. For instance, If I have a logic to be written in the backend based on the cssclass chosen in the Submit button. 
All I wanted to know is why the formsubmitcontext.fields is not considering the submit button as a field and render its field values.

Comment: button field value is used to apply attribute on submit button, this button is just like MVC form submit button where on form submit you will get all forms field value but not any attribute value.

Comment: Thank you so much @Swati Gupta for the explanation.